# Mutually exclusive counts in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

The table that I need to query looks like this

```
ID - Account - Product

1  - 002     - Bike         
2  - 003     - Bike         
4  - 003     - Motor        
5  - 004     - Car
```

I need to be able to retrieve the number of accounts that purchased the each of the products and combinations of the products, like this

```
Bike | Car | Motor | Bike&Car | Bike&Motor | Car&Motor | Bike&Car&Motor
```

Note that an account that purchased a combination of products will be counted as 1.

Please help me in retrieving this data.

Comment: So if an account purchased one bike and one car, how does the tally look?  Are there _three_ entries under bike, car, and bike&car, or just one entry?  Have you tried something yet?

Comment: and how does someone knows it's a combination?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen say an account purchased a motor alone, that will included in the count of motors, but if that account also purchased a car, he will be removed from motors' count and will be included in car&motor's count. single entry for every product purchased.

Comment: @MaryRoseVillanueva Are these all the products? Or do you want your columns to be dynamic?

Comment: @FelixPamittan, yes these are all products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using two levels of aggregation.  One method puts the values on different rows:

```
select has_bike, has_motor, has_car, count(*)
from (select account,
             max(case when product = 'bike' then 1 else 0 end) as has_bike,
             max(case when product = 'motor' then 1 else 0 end) as has_motor,
             max(case when product = 'car' then 1 else 0 end) as has_car
      from t
      group by account
     ) t
group by has_bike, has_motor, has_car;
```

Or in columns:

```
select sum(has_bike * (1 - has_motor) * (1 - has_car)) as has_only_bike,
       sum((1 - has_bike) * has_motor * (1 - has_car)) as has_only_motor,
       sum((1 - has_bike) * (1 - has_motor) * has_car) as has_only_car,
       . . .
from (select account,
             max(case when product = 'bike' then 1 else 0 end) as has_bike,
             max(case when product = 'motor' then 1 else 0 end) as has_motor,
             max(case when product = 'car' then 1 else 0 end) as has_car
      from t
      group by account
     ) t;
```

Comment: Does this exclude each counts from each other. Cause I am getting quite big results. I mean, for example, if an account purchased motor&car, that account should not be counted on motor's and on car's. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @MaryRoseVillanueva . . . The first version with `group by` definitely does not overcount.  For the second, you have to be sure the expressions are correct.

Comment: Used the first version! Thanks so much for your great help!

Answer (score 0):

If you only have a limited set of `Product`s, then you can use this:

```
-- Create sample data
CREATE TABLE #tbl(
    ID      INT,
    Account VARCHAR(10),
    Product VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO #tbl VALUES
(1, '002', 'Bike'),
(2, '003', 'Bike'),
(3, '003', 'Motor'),
(4, '004', 'Car');

WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT t1.Account, a.Products
    FROM #tbl t1
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT STUFF((
            SELECT '&' + t2.Product
            FROM #tbl t2
            WHERE t2.Account = t1.Account
            ORDER BY t2.Product
            FOR XML PATH(''), type).value('.[1]','nvarchar(max)'),
        1, 1, '')  AS Products
    ) a
    GROUP BY t1.Account, a.Products
)
SELECT
    Bike                = SUM(CASE WHEN Products = 'Bike' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    Car                 = SUM(CASE WHEN Products = 'Car' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    Motor               = SUM(CASE WHEN Products = 'Motor' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    [Bike&Car]          = SUM(CASE WHEN Products = 'Bike&Car' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    [Bike&Motor]        = SUM(CASE WHEN Products = 'Bike&Motor' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    [Car&Motor]         = SUM(CASE WHEN Products = 'Car&Motor' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    [Bike&Car&Motor]    = SUM(CASE WHEN Products = 'Bike&Car&Motor' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM Cte;

DROP TABLE #tbl; -- Remove sample data
```

The idea is to generate 1 row for each `Account`, together with a comma-delimited `Products`. If you execute the query inside the CTE, you will get:

```
Account    Products
---------- ---------------
002        Bike
003        Bike&Motor
004        Car
```

With that, you can do a conditional aggregation. The above uses a static solution, if you do not know the number of `Product`s, you may need to come up with a dynamic approach.

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](http://rextester.com/ZMIU19485)</kbd>